# SQL exclude all rows that with have certain value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table with these value, and here is a small sample

```
order   state   item id
10064315    ON  MCM1L162L116
10064315    ON  MCM1R162R116
10064315    ON  SHIPPING
10064316    MS  00801-1778
10064316    MS  SHIPPING
10064317    AZ  CHM110439-1
10064317    AZ  SHIPPING
10064318    TX  2607
10064318    TX  SHIPPING
10064319    MO  CHG8080
10064319    MO  SHIPPING
10064322    CA  W10001130
```

I want to write a sql query that only list on the order number that without SHIPPING, in this sample, the only one without SHIPPING would be 10064322.

I try to find in here but didn't find what I am looking for.

Thank for the help

Comment: look up `not exists`

Comment: @DanielE. I would expect `NOT IN` to be faster than `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: @Hogan: How so?  `EXISTS` checks for presence of a record, not for a specific value.  `IN` is normally bad for performance as is `NOT`.

Comment: Of course NOT EXISTS works correctly.

Comment: @TTeeple - Basically the SQL server can optimize by looking for distinct values of order in another thread -- if [order] is an index it can order them while it checks for shipping and at the same time join back to the main table.

Comment: @TTeeple - of course it depends on the platform.  DB2 for example is much better with not exists, so I would try that too on that platform.

Comment: @Hogan: Any decent optimizer should apply the same optimization for NOT IN or NOT EXISTS and create the same plan, **if** both columns are `NOT NULL`. Otherwise `NOT EXISTS` should perform better due to the simpler 2-way-logic.

Comment: @dnoeth - you don't think indexes will have an effect on the plan?

Comment: No indexes on the table (hence the Scans), these are the two different execution plans for the answers below: http://i.imgur.com/sFbr7IY.png.  I would personally take the second one over the first.  For a larger dataset, that Sort could potentially be huge.

Comment: @TTeeple not apples to apples -- the 2nd query does not do a distinct.  Take the Distinct out of mine or add it to his.  See mine is faster.

Comment: @Hogan I did so and they are the same plan BUT the `NOT EXISTS` returns less rows on the subquery.

Comment: @TTeeple I don't understand if plan is the same as the one you showed NOT EXISTS is doing an extra TOP 1 step.  how is that the same?

Comment: @TTeeple: Different results are bad, should be exactly the same  (unless there's some NULLs in the data). Try Giorgi Nakeuri's aggregation, too, should be the most efficient :-)

Comment: @dnoeth you are correct.  That is the most efficient.  But the discussion was between `NOT IN` vs `NOT EXISTS`.  I will defer to Aaron Bertrand's post since he gets more statistical than I do, http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT [order] 
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE [order] not in (SELECT [order] 
                      FROM MYTABLE 
                      WHERE [item id] = 'SHIPPING')
```

EDIT:

According to Aaron Bertrand's article (hat tip @TTeeple in the comments) the best performance for this problem (needing the distinct) is done as follows:

```
SELECT [order]
FROM MYTABLE
  EXCEPT
SELECT [order]
FROM MYTABLE 
WHERE [item id] = 'SHIPPING'
```

For the full article -> http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Comment: Personally this is the answer I was going to give and that I believe is the correct one.

Comment: @ChristianBarron - Thanks.  Welcome to Stackoverflow.  If you think an answer is correct you should up-vote it.  This carries even more weight than adding a comment.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `not exists`:

```
select ordernumber
from yourtable y
where not exists (
    select 1
    from yourtable y2
    where y.ordernumber = y2.ordernumber and y2.itemid = 'SHIPPING'
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select [order] from
table
group by [order]
having sum(case when [item id] = 'SHIPPING' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: It avoids the DISTINCT step needed for the other solutions :-)